# VBA emulation of WinWord's file compare for strings

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm replacing certain strings throughout a WinWord document with strings of a slightly different spelling with revision tracking being enabled.

Revision tracking will mark the whole original string as being deleted and the whole replacement string as being inserted. Anybody who is reviewing the text and wanting to know why a certain string has been replaced will have to visually compare both strings, even if they differ only in one or two characters.

I would much prefer if only the differing characters are being marked as revisions. That would probably mean that I have to emulate WinWords file compare function, albeit not for whole files but for strings within a given file. Has anybody already tried anything like that or a good idea of how to approach this task? (I know, it is possible to copy original and replacement string into 2 empty files, compare the files and use the result, but with hundreds of strings within a single file this is no practical solution.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to be more selective in how you're actually replacing the words. The built in Find/Replace works by replacing the entire word, but by utilising VBA you can be more specific about what is being replaced. So we still use the built in Find function to identify the words to be replaced, but then you could iterate through each character in the word and compare against your replacement text therefore only replacing what is necessary. I've commented to below code to explain how an example of this would work.

This would produce output as in the below examples, only highlighting the actual characters that have been changed.

[image: Example of Tracked Character Changes Only]

```
Sub replaceDifferencesOnly()

Dim findText As String: findText = "Analyze"
Dim replaceText As String: replaceText = "Analyse"
Dim found As Boolean: found = True

'   Using the built-in 'Find' Function, loop through each instance of
'   findText within the Document.
While found
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = findText
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    '   If findText is found within the Document...
    If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then

        Dim match As Range
        Dim char As Range
        Dim position As Integer: position = 1

        '   Transfer the Selections Range into a seperate Range object.
        Set match = Selection.Range

        For Each char In match.Characters

            Select Case Len(replaceText)

                Case Is >= position
                    '   If findText and replaceText are currently of an equal length...
                    '   Simply compare and replace differing character.

                    If Not char.Text = Mid(replaceText, position, 1) Then
                        char.InsertBefore Mid(replaceText, position, 1)
                        '   Inserting a Character will extend the size of the current 'character' or Range
                        '   Move the start position of the range on so as to only delete the original unwanted character.
                        char.MoveStart
                        char.Delete wdCharacter
                    End If

                Case Is < position
                    '   If replaceText is shorter than findText...
                    '   Simply delete the remaining unwanted characters in findText.
                    char.Delete

            End Select

            position = position + 1

        Next char

        If position <= Len(replaceText) Then
            '   Finally if replaceText is longer than findText ie. we've processed each original character in
            '   findText but there are still more characters in replaceText...
            '   Simply append the remaining characetrs within replaceText to the end of the Range

            match.InsertAfter Mid(replaceText, position, (Len(replaceText) - position) + 1)
        End If

    Else
        '   No match from Find so exit the routine as there is nothing more to replace.
        found = False
    End If
Wend

'   Clear the current Selected text.
Selection.Collapse
End Sub
```